# An elegant way of comparing values of unsorted arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have two arrays of ints in C and I would like to compare them. This is something VERY quick that I hacked together, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way.

1) Find an integer that is not in the array (arr2) we are comparing.
2) Copy that original array (arr2).
3) Iterate through the first array (arr1) and, if the element is found in the copied array, we replace the value at that index with the value we know was not in the original array (this is to prevent short-circuiting when multiple of the same values are in the array).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <random.h>


bool isin(int arr[], int elem, size_t len, size_t *index) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == elem) {
            if(index != NULL)
                *index = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int notInArray(int arr[], size_t len) {
    int r;
    do {
        r = rand();
    } while (isin(arr, r, len, NULL));
    return r;
}

bool arraysEqual(int arr1[], int arr2[], size_t len) {
    size_t i, j, index;
    int notInArr2 = notInArray(arr2, len);

    int *arr = (int*)malloc(len * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        arr[i] = arr2[i]; /*copy arr2 to arr*/

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (isin(arr, arr1[i], len, &index))
            arr[index] = notInArr2; /*replace that elemnt with something that we know is not in the original array*/
        else
            return free(arr), false;
    }
    free(arr);
    return true;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a[] = { 3, 9, 1, 3, 8 };
    int b[] = { 1, 8, 3, 3, 9 };
    printf("%i\n", arraysEqual(a, b, sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)));
    system("pause");
}
```

I'm not necessarily looking for a source code, but more a general idea of how I would implement it.

Comment: Use `memcpy` to copy arrays.

Answer (score 6):

From an algorithmic point of view, your solution is suboptimal and performs the comparison in `O(n^2)` time (because `isin` is called for every element in the array) and `O(n)` additional space (because you allocate a copy of the array).

There are cheaper ways of performing this task, here's a rundown of 5 alternative approaches:

- Compute a hashset or count-dictionary (frequency distribution) of one array and iterate over the other to determine matching value-histograms (`O(n)` time, `O(n)` space)
- The same as above, but use a Bloom Filter, provided you don't care for matching value frequency and don't mind the risk of false-positives (`O(n)` time, `O(1)` space)
- Sort one of the arrays in-place and use binary-search to detect matches (`O(n log n)` time for Quicksort, and `O(log n)` for binary-search, `O(1)` space).
- If the input arrays are immutable, then do the same as the above option but sort into a new array (same time complexity as above, but `O(n)` space)
- Sort both arrays and check all elements at the same index are equal (`O(2n log n)` time, `O(1)` space).

Answer (score 1):

You should abstract from C and look at the algorithmic problem for a moment.

Your proposed algorithm works in O(n^2). Answering your question, yes, there is a way to do this in O(n logn), or even O(n) if your integers are not huge. And this is a pretty simple exercise which you should try to do yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the element matched with a random number not in the array, I think you could have an array of Booleans that specified that a match was already found.  Then in your comparison, you could just omit those elements with a corresponding match found value of true.  That would save having to search for a value not in the array and there would be no need to copy the `arr2` to `arr`.